# readFileSync() doesn't return special characters regardless of encoding

Tags: node.js

My requirements are very simple… open any old ANSI-ASCII-UTF8-Unicode TXT file and replace some of the special "word processing" characters like the fancy single quote (\u2019) and double quotes (\u201C and \u201D) with the plain vanilla Ascii ones, and then do some other (irrelevant to the problem) parsing.

However, regardless of the encoding I try (ascii, utf8, binary) I just can’t get Node.js to return all characters correctly so as to replace them with their Ascii equivalents and instead I get the useless little rectangles!

Here’s the relevant part of the function…

```
function LoadTxtFile(Name){

fs=require('fs');

if (fs.existsSync(Name)){

var Source=fs.readFileSync(Name,'binary').toString();

/* Replace miscellaneous characters which works fine…*/
Source=Source.replace(/\©/g,'&#169;');
Source=Source.replace(/\…/g,'...');
Source=Source.replace(/\t/g,'&emsp;');
Source=Source.replace(/\'/g,'&#39;')

/* Replace the dreaded single/double quotes but they are never located! */
Source=Source.replace(/\u2019/g,'&#39;');
Source=Source.replace(/\u201C/g,'&#34;');
Source=Source.replace(/\u201D/g,'&#34;');

/* And we’re stuck! */

}}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Node-Iconv](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv) library see if it helps